# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com/sun/rowset/RowSetResourceBundle, locale en_US

Tags: junit, java-17

Upgraded java version from 1.8 to 17. Then had to change

CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl()

To

CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();

Following error is getting when run unit test

at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleFromModule(ResourceBundle.java:1603)
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1014)
at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.(JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.java:105)
at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.getJdbcRowSetResourceBundle(JdbcRowSetResourceBundle.java:124)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.(CachedRowSetImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl.createCachedRowSet(RowSetFactoryImpl.java:49)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see the full stack trace, so this is mainly an assumption.

Fast static check of the com.sun.rowset's code shows it uses reflection (via ReflectUtil), and has other places in the code that uses AccessController. Java added layers of security. You can add something like this to your build.gradle:
`test { jvmArgs '--add-opens', 'java.base/com.sun.rowset=ALL-UNNAMED' }`